# Azure Functions Redirect Header

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I want one of my Azure Functions to do an **HTTP Redirection**.

This is the current code of the function:

```
module.exports = context => {
  context.res.status(302)
  context.res.header('Location', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com')
  context.done()
}
```

But it does not work.

A request sent from Postman shows the response has:

- `Status`: 200
- `Location` not set

Is this correct code? Or is it simply not allowed by Azure Functions?

Comment: A better place to ask might be opening an issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script

Comment: That's the first time somebody tells me to open an issue instead of asking a question on SO. :)
In fact I wanted to know if this was correct code, and if it was allowed by Azure Functions before creating an issue on Github.

Comment: @kube, the code is indeed correct (as I mentioned below). I suspect you didn't see the behavior you expected because you were using $return as the binding name. I have more details below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code above actually does work, unless you have your binding name set to $return, which is what I assume you have now (you can check in the integrate tab)

Either of the following options will also do what you're looking for

Assuming $return in the binding configuration:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
var res = { status: 302, headers: { "location": "https://www.stackoverflow.com" }, body: null};
context.done(null, res);
};
```

Or using the "express style" API (not using $return in the binding configuration):

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
context.res.status(302)
            .set('location','https://www.stackoverflow.com')
            .send();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the details.
It works with your first solution.
But I don't know how to make your second solution work though.
Just removing the binding to `$return` (and leaving it empty) does not make it work.

Comment: This works fine but one thing to notice that make sure the redirect URL having the protocol, otherwise it will be assumed as https. As least this is happening for our azure function.

Comment: In my scenario, the second suggestion, the "express style", that redirected like I needed.

Comment: Hi @Fabio, thanks for the response, it work for me in localhost, but when perform a deploy don't work on my production server (the same code). Is necessary to move some other configuration on the server? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    res = {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            'Location': 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'
        },
        body: 'Redirecting...'
    };
    context.done(null, res);
};
```